# Check if the file is newer then some other file in Ruby?

Tags: ruby, file-io

In Ruby, how do I check if the file is newer than the target before copying?

I found in [Ruby-doc.org](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.0.0/libdoc/fileutils/rdoc/FileUtils.html#method-c-uptodate-3F) the `FileUtils.uptodate?`, but it doesn't seems to work.
I have this error message when running:

> /Users/bprov/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p451/lib/ruby/2.0.0/fileutils.rb:148:in `uptodate?': undefined method`each' for "/Users/bprov/folder2/homecontroller":String (NoMethodError)
>       from Test_Copy.rb:11:in `block in <main>'
>       from Test_Copy.rb:6:in`foreach'
>       from Test_Copy.rb:6:in `'

I have something like that:

```
require 'fileutils'

$sourcepath = "/Users/bprov/railsbridge"
$destinationpath = "/Users/bprov/folder2"

Dir.foreach($sourcepath)  do |file|
  if (file =~ /^\./ )
    # Do nothing
  else
    puts file
    if FileUtils.uptodate?($sourcepath + "/" + file, $destinationpath + "/" + file)
      # Do nothing
    else
      # If newer
      FileUtils.cp($sourcepath + "/" + file, $destinationpath + "/" + file)
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: You have `File.uptodate?` not `FileUtils.uptodate?`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

So, just use it properly:

```
FileUtils.uptodate?($sourcepath + "/" + file, [$destinationpath + "/" + file])
```

Comment: Very good idea!!
But I still have an error:

/Users/bprov/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p451/lib/ruby/2.0.0/fileutils.rb:148:in `uptodate?': undefined method `each' for #<String:0x00000101803598> (NoMethodError)

Comment: @BProv The documentation is here: https://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.5.1/libdoc/fileutils/rdoc/FileUtils.html#method-c-uptodate-3F. If you then patch the URL to match your Ruby version and more recent versions, you'll see that it was introduced in 2.1.0.